How to connect sales order line to assembly items in Netsuites
I am trying to get every sales order line with all the assembly itesm that went into the line so I can load the data into my data warehouse.
The background of my problem is that w have BOMs that change quite frequently and teams do not do it in a way that history is maintained. If I use the current BOM in my data warehouse then all the hostorical data will be wrong.
Is there any way to get each sales order line and the assembly items thatg went into it?
Addn. info:
I am not an expert on Netsuites but a different team suggested a solution of using 3 suiteQL queries,

Get all sales order lines and associated inventory number
Get all the inventory number and associated work orders
Get all work orders and the assembly items in them

With this approach there seems to be so many duplciates - a single inventory number having multiple associated WOs and so on.
